# How to derive or justify the expressions of momentum operator and energy operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, operators

It has been noted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/why-is-force-described-as-rate-of-change-of-momentum/27889#27889)$\! { \, }^{\text(1, 2)}$, for instance, that

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d}{dt}\!\!\biggl[ \, \mathbf{p} \, \biggr]$$

is true in all contexts.

Likewise, 
[in notable contexts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force#Mathematical_description) it is apparently true that

$$\mathbf{F} = - \nabla \Phi := - \frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}}\!\!\biggl[ \, \Phi \, \biggr].$$

Is this, in a nutshell, a sufficient and valid justification for setting (in the corresponding suitable contexts)
the [momentum operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Definition_.28position_space.29) as$\! { \, }^{\text(3)}$

$$\mathbf{\hat p } \propto -i \nabla := -i\frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}}$$

and setting the (potential) [energy operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_operator#Definition) as$\! { \, }^{\text(4)}$

$$\hat \Phi \propto i\frac{d}{dt}$$

and both with the same constant of proportionality, $\hbar$, whereby

$$\mathbf{\hat F} =  \frac{d}{dt}\biggl[-i\hbar\frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}}\biggr] = -\frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}} \biggl[i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\biggr] \sim \frac{d^2}{dt \, d\mathbf{r}} = \frac{d^2}{d\mathbf{r} \, dt}$$

?

**EDIT (related merely to formalities):**

(${ \, }^{\text 1}$: Please note that [the assertion to be noted *here*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/why-is-force-described-as-rate-of-change-of-momentum/27889#27889) had been expressed explicitly in the form

> $F = \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{p}}{\mathrm{d} t}$ is true in all contexts.

However, since it appears admissible to take note of an assertion without strictly quoting and clinging to its original literal expression (as had been tacitly presumed already in [the initial statement of my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/83902/1), and as it seems to be [thus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/83902/2) confirmed) I'd like, as far as unambiguously possible, to express the operation of ["*differentiation*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition) consistently by using (a form of) [*Leibniz's notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Leibniz.27s_notation).)

(${ \, }^{\text 2}$: Please note that [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/why-is-force-described-as-rate-of-change-of-momentum) whose [notable answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/why-is-force-described-as-rate-of-change-of-momentum/27889#27889) to which reference has been made above had been tagged (primarily) as has "*https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics*".)

($ { \, }^{\text 3}$: Please note that the indicated expression of the [*momentum operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Definition_.28position_space.29)
is explicitly stated there as

> ${\bf \hat p } = -i \hbar \nabla$

and

> In one spatial dimension this becomes: 
>   $\hat{p}=\hat{p}_x=-i\hbar{\partial \over \partial x}$,

where the nabla symbol ($\nabla$) is related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Notation .)

(${ \, }^{\text 4}$: Please note that the indicated expression of the [*energy operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_operator#Definition) is explicitly stated there as

> $\hat{E} = i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$.

)

Answer (score 4):

Note that forces are usually not well defined in a quantum mechanical context. Most forces (i.e. conservative, non-uniform force fields) are just ways of expressing position-dependent changes in momentum. For this to be a meaningful concept, we need position and momentum to be simultaneously well defined; and in quantum mechanics, they are not.

If you put together $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{\dot{p}}$ and $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})$, you get the expression $\mathbf{\dot{p}} = -\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})$. The left-hand side of this equation describes momentum, while the right-hand side is a function of position. But Heisenbergs uncertainty principle $\Delta p_i \Delta x_i \geq \hbar/2$ implies that position and momentum cannot be simultaneously well-defined, consequently the two sides of the equation are not simultaneously well-defined. This implies that this equation is invalid in quantum mechanics. (The connection to classical mechanics is basically that if you take the *expectation value* of both sides of the equation, it also holds in quantum mechanics. Google *Ehrenfests theorem* for more information about this.)

As for justifying the expressions for energy and momentum operators, perhaps my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83789/intuitively-re-deriving-equations-of-mathematical-physics/83805#83805) is somewhat relevant?

Comment: jabirali: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately it caught me in the middle of editing my question (which I did on formal grounds only). Also, unfortunately, I cannot at all address the contents of your answer at the moment; but I hope to be able to do that within the next 24 h.

Comment: "This implies that this equation is invalid in quantum mechanics". At least in Heinseberg representation, it is correct, as an equation between operators. For instance for the quantum harmonic oscillator, you have : $ \mathbf {\dot P}(t) = -m \omega^2 \mathbf {X}(t) $. See also this previous [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/81688/6316)

Comment: I was implicitly thinking in the Schroedinger picture, where the equation doesn't hold neither for operators ($\mathbf{p}$ is time-independent, so $\mathbf{\dot{p}} = 0$) nor for eigenvalues (not simultaneously well-defined). I stand corrected :)

Comment: jabirali: "_[...] perhaps my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83805) ..._" and there (final section): "_Technically, we say that the Hamiltonian is the generator of time translations, and momentum is the generator of space translations._" -- Yes, thanks, that seems relevant to what I'm trying to get at, namely: Is the expression $\mathbf{\dot{p}} = -\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})$ useful or even required for figuring out **which (if any) generator** (of "_time translations_", or "_space translations_", or "_rotations_", or who knows what) **to call/associate with "momentum, p"** ?